# Which Vishisthadvaita acharyas belonged to shakha of Shukla Yajurveda?

Tags: sri-vaishnava, agamas, pancharatra, shukla-yajurveda

In some answers, I read that Pancharatra agama originated from some of the shakha of Shukla Yajurveda which is extinct today.

So my question is which are the acharyas of their sri vaishnava tradition who belonged to Shukla yajurveda and their related sutras?

Comment: The Pancharatra Agamas are associated with the Ekayana Shakha of the Shukla Yajur Veda, which is now lost.  Do you want to know if there are any Sri Vaishnava Acharyas who belonged to the Ekayana Shakha, or do you just want to know if there are Sri Vaishnava Acharyas who belonged to any Shakhas of the Shukla Yajur Veda?

Comment: I don't know the answer to the first question; families often continue to belong to a Shakha even when the actual text of the Shakha is lost; for instance I belong to the lost Apastamba Shakha of the Krishna Yajur Veda. So it's possible that at the time of Nathamuni or Ramanujacharya there could have been Yajur Veda Brahmins who belonged to the Ekayana Shakha. As to the second question, most Yajur Veda Brahmins in South India belong to the Krishna Yajur Veda, but there are some Shukla Yajur Veda Brahmins in South India as well, so it's possible that one of them became a Sri Vaishnava Acharya.

Comment: By the way, the main place that Brahamanas of the Ekayana Shakha lived in in ancient times was Kashmir.  That is why the Pancharatra Agamas are sometimes called Kashmira Agamas.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan how do you know the Shakha to which you belong?

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan as most of the brahmins in south india belong to krishna yajurveda so i was curious to know that if vaishnavas from south india belonged to shukla yajurveda or not.

Comment: @user1952500 It's information that's been passed down in my family generation after generation.  The Vedic Shakha you belong to is recited during Abhivadanam, which is an utterance that you say during Sandhyavandhanam and other rituals. Here is my Abhivadanam: "Bhargava Vitahavya Savedasa Trayarishaya, Vadhula Gotraha, Apastamba Sutraha, Yajushakhadhyayi, Keshava Sharmanam Aham Asmi Bhoh" That means "Descended from the three rishis Bhrigu, Vitahavya, and Savedasa, from Vadhula Gotra, following Apastamba Sutra, following a Shakha of the Yajur Veda, I am the Brahmana named Keshava, salutations."

Comment: Thanks @KeshavSrinivasan. My Abhivadanam is identical except for the name, but I thought the Apastamba sutra to be another sutra like that of Manu and Goutama. There is an Apastamba sutra present as well, so can u tell me how u know if it pertains to the vedas or the way of life?

Comment: @user1952500 When we say Apastamba Sutraha, we are saying that we are following the Apastamba Grihya Sutras, which are the Grihya Sutra text of the Apastamba Shakha of the Krishna Yajur Veda.  Each Shakha of the Vedas has its own Grihya Sutra text.